# javascript form submit is not working in https

Tags: javascript, https, form-submit

javascript submit is not working in https.

javascript code

```
function apply()
{
    document.fileinfo.action='<%=uploadJSP%>';
    // uploadJSP = https://localhost/upload.jsp
    document.fileinfo.submit();
}
```

html code

```
<form name="fileinfo" action="upload.jsp" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
...
</form>
```

result of newtwork capture on IE developer tool,

```
...
DOMContentLoaded (event)‎‎  + 184ms -   
Load (event)‎‎  + 197ms -
```

on Load(event) break

This code is working normally on http (uploadJSP = http://loaclhost/upload.jsp)

I don't know what is wrong.
please advice for me to solve this problem

Comment: Please define "not working". Please provide additional network/console errors. Is this not a simple http/https (mixed content) mismatch?

Comment: not working is no response with error page. console error is DOM7011: The code on this page disabled back and forward caching. I find console error, but I can not solve. Both http and https is vaild url.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly,
Have you tried printing the value of `document.fileinfo.action` in your first snippet after it has been assigned = `"<%=uploadJSP%>"`?

`<%= {code} %>` is only processed when the server sends html documents, so if your script is in a separate file from your html, or your server doesn't process code in between `<script>` tags, then `document.fileinfo.action = "<%=uploadJSP%>"` instead of `document.fileinfo.action = "https://localhost/upload.jsp"` as intended.

Second, you don't need to set the action for the form again in javascript since it's already set in html. So, instead of worrying how you can pass the correct value in your first snippet, I would suggest removing the `document.fileinfo.action = "<%=uploadJSP%>"` line altogether.